# What is the equivalent unix command to a Mac OSX "Compress" menu action?

Tags: macos, unix, compression, zip, gzip

When I right-click a file in Mac OSX and select "Compress 'File Name'", what is the equivalent bash or terminal command to get the same result?

Is it just `gzip -9 /path/to/filename`?

Answer (score 6):

```
ditto -ck --rsrc --sequesterRsrc --keepParent folder folder.zip
```

`ditto -ck` uses Info-ZIP's zip.

Answer (score 2):

`gzip` is a different, incompatible algorithm.  It's better compression, and not encumbered by any patents, but it's only supported out of the box on Unix and Unix-like systems (including Linux and OSX, but not Windows).  What you're looking for is `zip`.  OSX ships with that as a command-line utility too.  See `man zip` for options.

Comment: +1 Not encumbered by any patents, nice.

Comment: The command-line zip (and the Compress menu item) use the same compression method as gzip, i.e. deflate.  The "better compression" you're thinking of could only be with respect to compressing a tar file as one thing with gzip, as opposed to the zip approach of compressing each file individually.  In any case, both gzip and Info-ZIP zip are not encumbered by any patents.

Answer (score 1):

If you 'Compress' a directory/folder called `myDir`, or something like that, then you get the equivalent of

```
% zip -r myDir.zip myDir
```

If you 'Compress' a single file, `f1`, then you get something like

```
% zip -r f1.zip f1
```

This is [Info-ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Info-Zip); there's a long and painful story about Info-ZIP vs [PKZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKZIP), which has patents and personalia aplenty.  As far as I'm aware, Info-ZIP is unencumbered.

You can unpack Zip archives with `unzip`, and list their contents with `unzip -l`.

Just by the way, one important difference between Zip and gzip is that Zip is both an archiver and a compressor, whereas gzip is designed only to compress single files.  The files that gzip compresses might be archive files (most commonly tar files), but the two jobs are separate.  If you want really good compression, then `bzip2` (see the man page) is reported to be more effective even than `gzip -9`.

Comment: The `zip` command doesn't include anything beyond basic file metadata in the archive, while the Finder includes them using the [AppleDouble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleDouble) format. To include the metadata, use `ditto` instead (see @Mark Adler's answer).

Comment: Ahaaa: thank you.  I was sure there had to be _some_ difference; I should have thought of looking at `ditto`.  It's good to know that the difference concerns only AppleDouble and resources.